# Magento 1- mage-report keeps saying the security patch isn't installed

Tags: magento1.9.3, magereport, supee-11219, supee-11155, security-patch

In **Magento 1.9.3.0** I have installed multiple patches **(supee-11314, supee-11155, supee-11219)** with the success message and also clear caches **(FPC, Redis, etc)**, **refer to screenshot 1**, but mage-report keeps saying the security patch isn't installed, **refer to screenshot 2**.
I have also cross-checked the random file which is changed after the patch applied, **refer to screenshot 3 & 4**.

**Screenshot 1:**
[image]

**Screenshot 2:**
[image]

**Screenshot3**
[image]

**Screenshot 4:**
[image]

Comment: Hi Aatif, I'm a developer on magereport. You might be experiencing a false-positive. We're aware that there are some false positives for these patches right now and are working on fixing them. If you want you can send your site specifically to magereport@hypernode.com to help us figure out where this is going wrong exactly. That being said I won't be in the office until tomorrow so you might have to wait a bit on a reply there.

Comment: Just to provide a little update: This was indeed a false-positive and has been fixed on our side :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, now it is working fine..